# Not able to select month drop down list in gmail sign up page.It is showing error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When trying to select the month using the below code it gives error.

```
Select s1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[title='Birthday']")).click());

s1.selectByIndex(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. update your question with the error that yor are.Also go through [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this forum. General [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: You are attempting to create a Selenium `Select` object from a web element that is a `div`. This cannot be done, and is likely the cause of your error. However, until you include the HTML source and the error you receive, we can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML page code, I'll assume that the Select has a title attribute of "Birthday."  Note that you do not need to click the select element to select one of its values, and I believe your css is incorrect, so my example uses xpath, again going on assumptions because you did not provide HTML code:

```
Select s1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@title='Birthday']");
s1.selectByIndex(0);
```

or

```
s1.selectByVisibleText("January");
```